# Dimensional analysis explanation and teacher issues!

Tags: dimensional-analysis

This is going to sound stupid but anyways. I am currently in a physics class and my teacher likes us to use [dimensional analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis) which I do not understand how to use or what to do with it! So firstly can someone explain that? And secondly, I can do all of the work (my way) and show all the work and my units, he just doesn't know "how I did it" but I still get the right answer and have all the work stated and he docks points for this, is that at all fair? Any opinions from other teachers would be greatly valued here.

Comment: Hi Mark. You're basically asking us to write an article on dimensional analysis. A quick Google should find you many such articles so there seems little point in writing yet another here. It's impossible to comment on how fair your teacher is being since we don't know the details. However dimensional anaylsis is an important skill and even we real physicists use it as a routine part of our work. Your teacher is right to insist you master it.

Comment: re: teacher.  You don't give us much to go on, but the phrase "how I did it" suggests he didn't understand your approach, starting point, procedure, handwriting, or all of the above.  *Getting the right answer is not good enough.* It's up to *you* to communicate effectively what you did.  I always dock points for poor communication.  Illegible submissions are simply given a zero.  I won't waste my time if a student has so little respect for him/herself and me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dimensional analysis helps you to find mistakes in your calculations, it is very useful. Let's say,you remember the expressions for the volume and the surface of a sphere but forgot which one is which. So you are unsure whether $\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$ or $4\pi r^2$ is the volume. Then you do dimensional analysis and see that the dimensions are $dim[\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3]=m^3$ ($m$ standing for meters) and $dim[4\pi r^2]=m^2$. On the other hand, obviously volume is measured in $m^3$ while surface is measured in $m^2$. By comparing those you know that the volume is $\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$ since it has the fitting dimension.

Another example: Say, you wrote down the equation describing free fall with a mistake:
$$h(t)=-\frac{1}{2}gt^3+v_0t+h_0$$

Then you check the dimensions of the terms:

$$dim[h(t)]=m$$
$$dim[h_0]=m$$
$$dim[v_0t]=dim[v_0]\cdot dim[t]=(m/s)\cdot m=m$$
$$dim[-\frac{1}{2}gt^3]=dim[g]\cdot dim[t^3]=(m/s^2)\cdot s^3=m\cdot s$$

And here you see that you made a mistake, since the dimensions of the summands don't match. Most probably the error is in the term $-\frac{1}{2}gt^3$ because this is the term that has a different dimension from all the other terms. And then you see that you have the dimension $m\cdot s$ instead of $m$ which is easy to fix by changing the term to $-\frac{1}{2}gt^2$ which has a lower power in $t$ and therefore the fitting dimension $m$.

I don't know whether your teacher is allowed to cut marks if you don't do the dimensional analysis, but in any case it's a very useful tool which becomes much more helpful in the future when the expressions grow bigger and offer more possibilities for potential mistakes.

Comment: Couldn't understand google at all, this made perfect sense! Thanks a lot!